# I get "TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException" even though I did define it

Tags: python, exception

according to python documents, Exception is derived from BaseExceptions and I should use it for user defined exceptions. so I have:

```
class VisaIOError(Exception):

    def __init__(self, error_code):
        abbreviation, description = _completion_and_error_messages[error_code]
        Error.__init__(self, abbreviation + ": " + description)
        self.error_code = error_code
```

And

```
 raise(visa_exceptions.VisaIOError, status)
```

but I get (trackback snippet):

```
   File "C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\vpp43.py", line 400, in check_status

    raise(visa_exceptions.VisaIOError, status)
    TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

Note: I am converting code from python 27 to 32

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have to do :

```
raise visa_exceptions.VisaIOError(status)
```

Comment: Yes. You were trying to raise a tuple: `(visa_exceptions.VisaIOError, status)`. That's where the `TypeError` came in.