# SystemExit exception not seen as derived from BaseException

Tags: python, exception

I'm currently trying to implement some code, and if it fails, I want to raise an exception with a specific message.
I want to use a basic exception, SystemExit, which is supposed to derive from BaseException. I import sys module

I raise the exception this way:

```
add_ip = None
# search for the ip address associated with the equipment's mac address
for i in range(0, len(add_match)):
    found = add_match[i].find(add_mac)
    if found != -1:
        add_ip = add_match[i].split()[0]

// it turns out that I don't find the matching IP address

if add_ip is not None:
    print("@IP =\t", add_ip)  # log matching IP
else:
    raise (SystemExit, "failure retrieving interface's IP address")
```

When I hit my case, I end up with an error indicating

```
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

I searched for a solution and found this one : [I get "TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException" even though I did define it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819353/i-get-typeerror-exceptions-must-derive-from-baseexception-even-though-i-did-d)
and modified my code as:

```
raise SystemExit("failure retrieving interface's IP address")
```

but I end up with having the same failure ...
Does anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

thank you

Alexandre

EDIT:
When I go to definition for SystemExit, I get that :

```
class SystemExit(BaseException):
  """ Request to exit from the interpreter. """

  def __init__(self, args, kwargs):
    pass

  code = None
```

Comment: Your second attempt works on my machine. Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates that code raising a TypeError?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit says that SystemExit has been derived from BaseException since Python 2.5. Are you using Python 2.4? Please consider upgrading.

Comment: can you show your `SystemExit` class body @A.Joly

Comment: It looks like you are raising a tuple...

Comment: @Kevin : I updated my code. I'm currently using Python 3.6.1. I'm getting a list of IP/Mac addresses and I find the matching line. In this case I didn't find the matching line

Comment: @Sanket: I added information at bottom.

Comment: When you say "I end up with having the same failure", do you mean "I got a TypeError again", or do you mean "I got a TypeError with the error message `exceptions must derive from BaseException`"? When I run your class definition and code, I get `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`, which is _not_ the same as your first error. What is the exact error your second attempt gives you?

Comment: Perhaps your `SystemExit` class should have a constructor like this: `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):` (Note the stars).

Comment: Alternatively, you should not have a constructor at all, because `SystemExit` is a built-in exception type, so you don't need to make your own class version of it.

Comment: I have the same error with the same message. I understand that it is a built-in exception type, so I tried to find where it comes from andwhen I point to SystemExit, it opens the following file : C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE Personal 6.0\resources\builtin-pi-files\3.6\builtins.pi. Maybe it is linked to my IDE but I find it strange somehow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 
I don't know what happened but now it works.
Actually, due to a new way to extract my ip address, I changed the algorithm in order to get ip scanning data from a file and not from a windows command (arp -a is too limited for my purpose) so I modified the code as follows:

```
add_ip = None

# parse a previousely saved Angry-IP export
try:
    with open ("current_ip_scan.txt", "r") as scan_file:
        for line in scan_file:
            line = line.upper()
            line = re.sub(r':','-', line)
            if (re.search(add_mac, line)) is not None:
                add_ip = re.findall('(([0-9]{2,3}\.){3}[0-9]{3})',line)[0][0] # to get the first element of the tuple
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("*** Angry-IP export not available - do it into 'current_ip_scan.txt' in order to find the matching IP address ***")
    raise SystemExit("failure retrieving interface's IP address")

if add_ip is not None:
    # check that the ip address is a valid IP
    if(re.match('(([0-9]{2,3}\.){3}[0-9]{3})', add_ip)) is not None:
        print("@IP =\t", add_ip)  # log matching IP
    else:
        raise SystemExit("failure retrieving interface's IP address")
else:
    #sys.exit("failure retrieving interface's IP address")
    raise SystemExit("failure retrieving interface's IP address")

return add_ip
```

I tried both, sys.exti and raise SystemExit and both now work (?).
@kevin @ sanket: Thank you for your help and your time

Alexandre